# jquery: tinysort.. "unsort" method to restore default order?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using tinysort plugin on jQuery and it works great.

However I would like if there is an "unsort" option, to restore the default order of my elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

> var alphaOrder = defaultOrder.clone();

and then:

> defaultOrder.remove();
>   alphaOrder.tsort("label").each(function(i){$(this)});
>   tagsDiv.append(alphaOrder);

and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be output the index of your list items (or whatever) in a hidden span and then in your undo button sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had a similar problem and I came up with a different solution. So, hopefully, this might help future users:

Before running tsort on your elements, try looping over all of them and setting an order using data attributes:

```
n = 1;
$('ul>li').each(function(index, value) {
    $this = $(this);  // cache for speed/memory usage
    $this.data({'orig': n});
}
// do other stuff you might want to do
$('#unsort').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul>li').tsort({data:'orig',order:'asc'});
});
```